# How to execute the same task with gulp, synchronously, once per each folder (in a monorepo with subpackages)?

Tags: node.js, gulp

I have the following project structure (monorepo with many packages)

```
  /pkgA
    gulpfile.js
  /pkgB
    gulpfile.js
  /pkgC
    gulpfile.js
```

Each package has a `gulpfile.js` which just loads `/shared/shared-gulp-tasks.js`

*Important: we want to keep this independence (so that I can run `gulp whatever` only for a given package, if wanted) - i.e. I don't want to remove the existing tasks from the shared gulpfile, I want to reuse them.*

If we want to build **everything at once**, we run a task synchronously like this:

```
bash for-each-package.sh "gulp package"
```

Which does something like

```
  cd pkgA
  gulp package
  cd pkgB
  gulp package
  cd pkgC
  gulp package
```

**However this is slow, because I start `gulp` executable from scratch for each package, and it takes ~3 seconds every time to load gulp and all the needed deps.** (we have 20+ subpackages).

What I want is to have a task defined in `gulpfile.js` in the root which would let me do

```
gulp package-all
```

The code would look like this:

```
  gulp.task('package-all', function(done) {
    ['pkgA', 'pkgB', 'pkgC'].forEach(function(pkgName) {
      process.chdir(path.join(__dirname, pkgName));
      // need to run 'package' task here, synchronously
      // gulp.start('package'); is async
    });
    done();
  }
```

Note that folder-specific `package` task is already declared in shared gulpfile and I don't want to rewrite it.

The problem is that I want to do this synchronously, and when all folders are finished processing, call `done()`.

Options explored so far:

- `gulp.run` is deprecated, `gulp.start` is undocumented, generally not advised
  and they don't work in this case (they are async)
- `runSequence` looks promising, but how would I run same task many times, per-folder, with `cd` to that folder before

I am aware that what I ask is kind-of orthogonal to "the gulp way" but I don't want to rewrite all my tasks.

What can be a good way to achieve my goals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I solved the issue by using `run-sequence` and creating fake tasks (not sure if there's an easier way - BTW it seems that gulp tasks can not be anonymous, you can't just pass functions to `run-sequence`, you need to pass string names of registered gulp tasks) and then a sequence out of those tasks (and passing `done` at the end of the sequence).

gulpfile.js

```
var runSequence = require('run-sequence');
var gulp = require('gulp');
require('./shared-gulp-tasks')(gulp);

var folders = ['pkgA', 'pkgB', 'pkgC']; // this array comes from external helper method which reads it from disk

function registerTaskForAllFolders(wrappedTaskName) {
  var tasksToExecute = [];

  folders.forEach(function(folderName) {
    var taskName = wrappedTaskName + '_' + folderName;
    gulp.task(taskName, function(done) {
      console.log(folderName);
      process.chdir(path.join(__dirname, folderName));
      runSequence(wrappedTaskName, done);
    });
    tasksToExecute.push(taskName);
  });

  gulp.task(wrappedTaskName + '-all', function(done) {
    tasksToExecute.push(done);
    runSequence.apply(null, tasksToExecute);
  });
}

// this registers a task called 'nothing-all'
registerTaskForAllFolders('nothing');

// this registers a task called 'clean-all'
registerTaskForAllFolders('clean');

// this registers a task called 'package-all'
registerTaskForAllFolders('package');
```

shared-gulp-tasks.js

```
module.exports = function(gulp) {
  gulp.task('nothing', function(done) {
    console.log('doing nothing in ' + process.cwd());
    done();
  });
}
```

terminal

```
gulp nothing-all
```

output

```
[17:08:51] Starting 'nothing-all'...
[17:08:52] Starting 'nothing_pkgA'...
[17:08:52] Starting 'nothing'...
doing nothing in d:\git\myproject\pkgA
[17:08:52] Finished 'nothing' after 171 μs
[17:08:52] Finished 'nothing_pkgA' after 2.23 ms
[17:08:52] Starting 'nothing_pkgB'...
[17:08:52] Starting 'nothing'...
doing nothing in d:\git\myproject\pkgB
[17:08:52] Finished 'nothing' after 2.03 ms
[17:08:52] Finished 'nothing_pkgB' after 11 ms
[17:08:52] Starting 'nothing_pkgC'...
[17:08:52] Starting 'nothing'...
doing nothing in d:\git\myproject\pkgC
[17:08:52] Finished 'nothing' after 1.93 ms
[17:08:52] Finished 'nothing_pkgC' after 11 ms
[17:08:52] Finished 'nothing-all' after 345 ms
```